# Getting a div to sit beside another

Tags: css

I can't get `.block-description` and `.block-img` to sit beside each other inside a wrapper `.block`.

```
.block { 
background-color:#E3DF8A;
width:100%;
 }

.block-description {
display: inline-block;
width:50%;
}

.block-img{
display: inline-block;
width:50%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6z23v1e8/

Comment: You could try bootstraping: http://getbootstrap.com/. It allows such functionalities along different screen sizes.

Comment: Could you please post a picture of what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be `display: table` will do the trick

```css
#right-panel {
    background-color:#DB9395;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
.block {
    background-color:#E3DF8A;
    width:100%;
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
.block-description {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    width: 50%;
}
.block-img {
    display: table-cell;
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="right-panel">
  <div class="block" id="1">
    <div class="block-description">
      <span class="block-description-span">Modurra Shelving</span>
    </div>
    <img class="block-img" alt="" src="http://www.newton.ac.uk/files/covers/968361.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing

```
.block {
background-color:#E3DF8A;
width:100%;
}
```

to

```
.block {
background-color:#E3DF8A;
width:100%;
white-space:nowrap;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6z23v1e8/1/

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
.block:after {
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    clear: both;
}
.block-description {
    display: inline-block;
    width:50%;
}
.block-img {
    display: inline-block;
    width:50%;
    float: left;
}
```

And to switch what block is in the front just switch the float to the other element.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mudd2L0g/

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using the Flexible Boxes model which is a new layout-mode made to improve upon the standard box model by replacing the `float:` property.

For browser compatibility reasons using ***Flexible Boxes*** consult this - [Compatibility Chart](http://caniuse.com/)

I used HTML5 semantic tags (section, figure, article) in the example code below to add clarity and "definitive" meaning to your page content, increasing SEO.

---

#### Related Information

- [Flexible Boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes)
- [HTML5 Semantics](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp)

---

[Here is the **JSFiddle** Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/agwog7rq/)

Screenshot:

[image]

//HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css"
</head>
<body>
    <section id="left-panel"></section>
    <section id="right-panel">
        <article>
            <figure>
                <img src="http://www.newton.ac.uk/files/covers/968361.jpg">
            </figure>
            <h1>Modurra Shelving</h1>
        </article>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

//CSS

```
body{
    margin: 0 !important;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
}   
#left-panel{
    background: #5c5c5c;
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
}
#right-panel{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
        
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
    background: #ECF0F1;    
}
article{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;  
}
h1{
    -webkit-align-self: center;
    align-self: center;
}
```